# Can i use the same component inside component in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```js
import React from 'react';

class Feladatlista extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
    }
    feladatok = () => {
        if(this.props.fl.length){
            this.props.fl.map(fl => {
                return <Feladatlista tipus={fl.tipus} nev={fl.nev} rang={fl.rang} fl={fl.fl}/>
            })
        }
    }
    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <div className={this.props.tipus}>
                    <p>{this.props.nev}</p>
                    <p>{this.props.rang}</p>
                </div>
                <div className='gyerek'>
                    {this.feladatok}
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
export default Feladatlista;
```

Here is my code. My plan is, to have a database with nested objects, where i push the data with the same components connected with each other. Like this:

```js
const feladat = [
  {név: 'asd',
  tipus: 'a',
  rang: '1',
  fl:[
    {név: 'dd',
    tipus: 'a',
    rang: '1',
    fl: []},
    {név: 'eded',
    tipus: 'a',
    rang: '2',
    fl: [
      {név: 'das',
      tipus: 'a',
      rang: '1',
      fl: []},
      {név: 'dasd',
      tipus: 'a',
      rang: '2',
      fl: [
        {név: 'dasd',
        tipus: 'a',
        rang: '1',
        fl: []
        }]
      }]
    }]
  }
]
```

In this way, in the main (App.js) i define the first element, and it loops through all of the array. But i get the error message: `index.js:2178 Warning: Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of <Component /> from render. Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it.`. The problem is that i want to use the same component in the component, or other?

Comment: You forgot to call the `feladatok` function in the render method. Should be `{this.feladatok()}` instead of `{this.feladatok}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you need to return the data from `feladatok`,
Second, you need to call the function from render like `this.feladatok()`

```
class Feladatlista extends React.Component {
  feladatok = () => {
    if (this.props.fl.length) {
      return this.props.fl.map((fl, index) => {
        return (
          <Feladatlista
            key={index}
            tipus={fl.tipus}
            nev={fl.nev}
            rang={fl.rang}
            fl={fl.fl}
          />
        );
      });
    }
    return null;
  };
  render() {
    console.log(this.props.fl);
    return (
      <div>
        <div className={this.props.tipus}>
          <p>{this.props.nev}</p>
          <p>{this.props.rang}</p>
        </div>
        <div className="gyerek">{this.feladatok()}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**[Working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/lxy3ppj0wm)**